# Mysql, random people from city table based in population

Tags: mysql, sql, math

I have a table with all the cities in the world and the population. And I want to get a random person in the world based in the city population.

I made this:

```
SELECT city_name FROM cities ORDER BY population * RAND() DESC;
```

After I put 100k users in another table. I saw that they were almost just from big cities. And small cities didn't have any chance.

I showed for a Math guy here, and he said I made wrong, I should use:

```
SELECT city_name FROM cities ORDER BY -LOG(1-RAND()) / population ASC;
```

his way works perfectly!

I said "ah ok", but the true is... I have no idea why!

Can you explain me why?

Comment: RAND() is a number between 0 and 1. So if you 1-RAND(), you still get a RANDOM NUMBER! Why bother 1-RAND()? Anyway, if you get the log of rand(), you get a negative number so we want to get a positive number. This explains -LOG(etc).  You divide by population because you are giving "equally" chance for both big and smaller cities. If log(RAND) number is big and city is small, then it might be the same or greater than log(RAND) is small and city is big.

Comment: I'd question "perfectly" -- that's more like "*more what you expected*". Which begs the question: **what is it that you expected?** What does "a random person .... based on city population" *mean*?

Comment: After make it 100k times.  I checked the "percent" of each city. And "perfectly" means that using LOG it gets the same percents as the original city table. Just using RAND() it gets pretty wrong percent. with big cities getting almost all the random values

Answer (score 0):

To simplify the task, let's say you have 2 cities A with 7 people, and B with 3 people, and the beginning order is (you can put in any order, it doesn't matter)

```
[B,B,B,A,A,A,A,A,A,A]
```

Now let's randomize a "value" for each person, for example, I do this with javascript and get 10 number:

```
var values = []; for (i=0;i< 10; i++) { values.push(Math.round(Math.random()*100)/100)}

 [0.97, 0.34, 0.99, 0.53, 0.16, 0.12, 0.21, 0.17, 0.61, 0.86]
```

When you use "ORDER BY value DESC", you will get the order as:

```
[A,A,B,B,A,A,A,B,A,A]
```

Taking top 5, you will get 3A and 2B

Now... let multiple the random value list with the population (*7 for A and *3 for B), the new values will be:

[2.58, 1.83, 0.51, 6.93, 6.79, 3.71, 2.38, 1.47, 1.12, 0.84]

the new order is:

```
[A,A,A,B,A,B,A,A,A,B]
```

Top 5: 4A and 1B now

So, as you can see, without multiplying with population, A has more number of people in the top than B. Multipling just makes it even more likely. While dividing, in opposite, will make the distribution more balanced

Comment: But, what Log() helps in the math?

Comment: In theory, it should work without Log(). But Log() helps to get a more precise number. Because, Rand() gives you a number between 0 and 1. When you divide rand()/population, if population is very big, some of the results might be round to 0, therefore they will be equal (though they are not). While -Log(x) (x in (0,1) ) is a number from 1 to infinite, which makes the results look better